# Form Validation not responding correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a simple script to check my form data upon submission. However it's not supposed to keep sending if the inputs are empty. Why isn't it working?

```
          <script src="scripts/formvalidate.js"></script>
          <h3 id="required">Contact Me</h3>
          <form name="form" onsubmit="return formValidate()" method="POST">
            <label for="name">Name<span id="asterisk" id="label"></span></label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
            <label for="email">Email<span id="asterisk" id="label"></span></label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
            <label for="subject">Subject<span id="asterisk" id="label"></span></label>
            <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject">
            <label for="message">Message<span id="asterisk" id="label"></span></label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>

function formValidate() {
    var form = document.forms["form"];
    var name = form.elements["name"].value;
    var email = form.elements["email"].value;
    var subject = form.elements["subject"].value;
    var message = form.elements["message"].value;
    var result = false;
    var output = "*";
    var required = "Required";
    var asterisk = "* ";
    if (name == "" || email == "" || subject == "" || message == "") {
        document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = output;
        document.getElementById("asterisk").innerHTML = asterisk;
        document.getElementById("required").innerHTML = required;
        alert('Please fill out all fields');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert('Thanks for contacting me');
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You need to add e.preventDefault(); to stop the submission and check the validation

Comment: `span id="asterisk" id="label"` - what is that supposed to mean?   Where is an element with id "required"?

Comment: I would recommend using something like https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can't use multiple elements with the same id's since an Id is supposed to identify a **uniquely** an element of the page ([HTML5 Specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute) says: ID must be document-wide unique.), try to use classes instead, and change your ***getElementById()*** to ***getElementsByClassName()*** just like this and it should work fine:

```js
function formValidate() {
    var form = document.forms["form"];
    var name = form.elements["name"].value;
    var email = form.elements["email"].value;
    var subject = form.elements["subject"].value;
    var message = form.elements["message"].value;
    var output = "*";
    var required = "Required";
    var asterisk = "* ";
    if (name == "" || email == "" || subject == "" || message == "") {
        document.getElementsByClassName("label").innerHTML = output;  //notice how I changed the function used here
        document.getElementById("asterisk").innerHTML = asterisk;
        document.getElementById("required").innerHTML = required;
        alert('Please fill out all fields');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert('Thanks for contacting me');
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="formvalidate.js"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
          <h3 id="required">Contact Me</h3>
          <form name="form" onsubmit="return formValidate()" method="POST">
            <label for="name">Name<span id="asterisk" class="label"></span></label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
            <label for="email">Email<span id="asterisk" class="label"></span></label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
            <label for="subject">Subject<span id="asterisk" class="label"></span></label>
            <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject">
            <label for="message">Message<span id="asterisk" class="label"></span></label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that the *asterisk* you try to insert, is only inserted in one input for the same reason noted before (multiple ID's are senseless to the DOM). as the DOM tries to fix that, it only get's the first element on the document with the given id *(to fix it just change **id="asterisk"** types to **class="asterisk"** type)*.

**Plot twist:** the reason you probably didn't see any error screen was because (I guess) you were testing it on chrome, which only shows the error for a millisecond. my personal advise is to use firefox for testing purposes, since it won't hide any error at all.

Comment: I only changed the script, since changing from id="asterisk"  to class="asterisk" could affect his site view or other methods on his side, that is why I pointed it out on the end so that he can apply the proper changes :)

Comment: just edited the answer to make it clearer. thanks for the feedbag.